# What elegant method callback design should be used?

Tags: c++, design-patterns, methods, callback, c++11

I'm surprised this question wasn't asked before on SO (well, at least I couldn't find it).

Have you ever designed a method-callback pattern (something like a *"pointer"* to a class method) in C++ and, if so, how did you do it ?

I know a method is just a regular function with some hidden `this` parameter to serve as a *context* and I have a pretty simple design in mind. However, since things are often more complex than they seem to, I wonder how our C++ *gurus* would  implement this, preferably in an *elegant* and standard way.

All suggestions are welcome !

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[boost::function](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/doc/html/function.html) for single callback, [boost::signal](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/doc/html/signals.html) or [boost::signals2](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/doc/html/signals2.html) when more than one callbacks can be registered, using [boost::bind](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/bind/bind.html) to bind member methods (or adapting the signatures in different ways).

If you have access to a compiler with C++0x/C++11 support it may have std::function and std::bind that are the new standard version of boost::function and boost::bind

Comment: Thanks. Boost is really astonishing. Is there anything this library can't do ?

Comment: it can't yet bring about world peace. There was a library in development to do this, but the developers couldn't agree on the syntax.

Comment: @Phil - nope, they just started fighting over bracing styles

Comment: @David: It's going to be a few years before I get used to the name C++11. Was just about to ask if you were referring to version 11 of some specific compiler or what you were talking about... ;)

Answer (score 2):

Isn't `boost::function` (in conjunction with `boost::bind`) elegant enough? This will also keep you away from nasty (yet standard-conforming) implementation details like pointers to members being larger than a `void*`, which was a problem in a callback library for an older Windows CE system. I'd rather use a well-known library than having to deal with these problems myself.

Comment: "I'd rather use a well-known library than having to deal with these problems myself." I totally agree with that. Just to know, does `boost::function` require me to link with boost or is it "template" based (just like `boost::shared_ptr`) ?

Comment: @ereOn: I think it's template-based only, since we're using it in a large project and only link to boost::thread. But I don't know for sure.

Comment: It's template based and header only. And if you have a modern compiler you probably have access to `std::tr1::function` (and `std::tr1::bind`) too - no need to wait for C++0x

Comment: @Phil Nash & @OregonGhost: Thanks to both of you. It's good to know. I'll certainly use it.

Answer (score 2):

A good introduction into callbacks with C++ you can find [here](http://www.newty.de/jakubik/callback.pdf). I used this paper as base for an implementation when boost was not an option.